# Why is Unity repeatedly giving me the same "XRStats::SetStatFloat failed" error?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, virtual-reality

I'm developing a VR application in Unity using Unity XR.
After programming for a while, my console showed the same error repeatedly:

> XRStats::SetStatFloat failed. Stats queue full! Stats for this frame
> will be lost.

I read that you should remove the *Test framework package* but this was without success.

```
void Start()
{
    List<InputDevice> devices = new List<InputDevice>();
    InputDeviceCharacteristics rightControllerCharacteristics = InputDeviceCharacteristics.Right | InputDeviceCharacteristics.Controller;
    InputDevices.GetDevicesWithCharacteristics(rightControllerCharacteristics, devices);

    foreach (var item in devices)
    {
        Debug.Log(item.name + item.characteristics);
    }

    if(devices.Count > 0)
    {
        targetDevice = devices[0];
    }
}


void Update()
{
    targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.primaryButton, out bool primartButtonValue);
    if (primartButtonValue)
    {
        Debug.Log("Primary trigger");
    }

    targetDevice.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.trigger, out float triggerValue);
}
```

I removed the script that is referenced above and still getting the same message. I've tried removing and installing all XR plugins but nothing works.

Comment: Hi @peppe you can share some lines of codes to make this question more informative. So, everyone who sees this post can directly understand what you need.

Comment: @Willysatrionugroho I´ve added some code now. Do you have any ide what the problem is? I kinda new to unity so it's not imposible that it's something obvious

Comment: I'd say that's a warning and not an error, but would be annoying nonetheless! When exactly does this happen (e.g. when your code is running, or seemingly randomly when you're writing your code)?

Comment: @AStopher first of sorry I'm new to unity and don't really know what everything is called yet. But the message fills my whole console (the warning sign i the right corner says 999+) everytime I press play

Comment: @peppe It's likely something in your `Update` Monobehaviour then, what happens if you comment that code out?

Comment: @AStopher The code doesn't really do anything exempt whriting some logs so I removed it to test if the warning would go away. BUT it keep coming...